# How can I make the height of two separate unordered list items the same height?

Tags: css, flexbox, less

For context, here's what it looks like. In the second unordered list, I would like the items to have the same height as the items in the first unordered list even though they don't have sections 2 or 3. Is this possible using flexbox or any other type of css? I'm trying to avoid calculating heights using JS. In the snippet below, I'm using pure css, but in my actual code, I'm using less.

EDIT: I can't hard-code the height because the sections are dynamic and generated by data retrieved from an API. Additionally, I can't make them vertically scrollable.

[image]

Code:

```
<html>

<head>
    <style>
        .module {
            display: flex;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
            justify-content: space-between;
        }

        .module .container_wrapper {
            border: solid 1px;
        }

        .module .panes-2 {
            flex: 0 0 49%;
        }

        .module .card {
            display: inline-block;
            border: solid 1px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <section class="module">

        <div class="container_wrapper panes-2">
            <ul>
                <li class="card">
                    <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/132/200/200.jpg?hmac=meVrCoOURNB7iKK3Mv-yuRrvxvXgv4h2vIRLM4sKwK4"
                        alt="">
                    <p>section 1</p>
                    <p>section 2</p>
                    <p>section 3</p>
                </li>
                <li class="card">
                    <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/132/200/200.jpg?hmac=meVrCoOURNB7iKK3Mv-yuRrvxvXgv4h2vIRLM4sKwK4"
                        alt="">
                    <p>section 1</p>
                    <p>section 2</p>
                    <p>section 3</p>
                </li>
                <li class="card">
                    <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/132/200/200.jpg?hmac=meVrCoOURNB7iKK3Mv-yuRrvxvXgv4h2vIRLM4sKwK4"
                        alt="">
                    <p>section 1</p>
                    <p>section 2</p>
                    <p>section 3</p>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="container_wrapper panes-2">
            <ul>
                <li class="card">
                    <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/132/200/200.jpg?hmac=meVrCoOURNB7iKK3Mv-yuRrvxvXgv4h2vIRLM4sKwK4"
                        alt="">
                    <p>section 1</p>
                </li>
                <li class="card">
                    <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/132/200/200.jpg?hmac=meVrCoOURNB7iKK3Mv-yuRrvxvXgv4h2vIRLM4sKwK4"
                        alt="">
                    <p>section 1</p>
                </li>
                <li class="card">
                    <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/132/200/200.jpg?hmac=meVrCoOURNB7iKK3Mv-yuRrvxvXgv4h2vIRLM4sKwK4"
                        alt="">
                    <p>section 1</p>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </section>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: use "height: 300px " or more in .module .card

Comment: Thank you for the reply! However, I can't set a hard-coded value. The data is generated from an API and I might have more than 3 sections. I would like the items to take the height of the largest item overall.

Comment: If I were you, I would use max-height or viewHeight property and make the content's <div> scrollable. In case you don't know what could be the size of the content below it.

Comment: Thanks for the continued investigation! Unfortunately, I can't make them scrollable.

Comment: Added an answer, you can check it.

Comment: Give `display: flex` to `.panes-2` and it's child `ul`.

Comment: @VXp - That works in this example, thank you! I'm going to try to add it to my real project and see how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

I did a little research.
Not sure if this is what you are looking for, but using bootstrap could help:

```
<div class="container-fluid content-row">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-6">
            <div class="card h-100">
                … content card …
            </div>
        </div>
        … all the other cards … 
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks again! From what I can tell, bootstrap is relying on a fixed height for the container which is something I can't use.

Answer (score -1):

```
.card {
height: 500px;
overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Also you can use overflow-y: auto;

Comment: I can't use fixed heights or scrolling

Comment: then remove overflow-y line and just keep simple height;

Comment: I can't use fixed heights.

Comment: then last solution is to use height:95%. it will stretch the div to bottom.